# Split the [dolphin] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[dolphin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin) is currently used for both the file manager and the [Dolphin emulator](https://dolphin-emu.org/).

The tag info says:

> File manager for KDE

As there are only 13 questions tagged with [dolphin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin), and as I don't have enough rep to retag myself, could someone retag the questions appropriately and edit the tag description to clarify that it is **not** for the emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be tempted to split the dolphin tag into [dolphin-file-manager](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin-file-manager) and [dolphin-emulator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin-emulator) and let [dolphin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin) get deleted.

They are two items that are quite distinct and [dolphin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin) isn't clear enough to say what it is about if there are two software packages with the same name.

---

Per the above and fixer1234s comments below [dolphin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin) has been renamed to [dolphin-file-manager](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin-file-manager) and relevant questions have been retagged [dolphin-emulator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dolphin-emulator).

The base dolphin tag has been deleted as I don't see a compelling reason to create a synonym in this case.

Comment: There are only a couple of questions for dolphin-emulator, and those are easy enough to retag.  Can the existing dolphin tag then be renamed to dolphin-file-manager to handle the rest in a single step?

Comment: I went ahead and retagged the two questions with a new dolphin-emulator tag and created a brief tag wiki for it.  The remaining 11 questions all relate to the file manager.  The existing dolphin tag already has a tag wiki related to the file manager.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, the tag can be renamed in a single step and I have done so.  Cheers for retagging the couple of questions that needed it.